# req.session.user undefined through AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, session, express

I'm building a website in MEAN, and for authentication and remembering user data, I use the req.session in the Node backend.
So I start storing the data when the user is logging in, and re-using it for certain calls. The problem is that when I do the call from my front-end in Angular, the req.session.user data is undefined. Even though It is correctly initialised.

But, when I use the same code and do the calls through Postman it works just fine.

This is my code for the call:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + auth.getToken();
console.log($http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization);
if($scope.production = true) {
    $http.post('http://url:3000/newproductie', {
        title: $scope.title,
        year: $scope.year
    }, {withCredentials: true}).success(function(data) {
        $location.path('/success')
    });
}
```

And this is the code in the backend:

```
if (req.session.user.isadmin) {
   // my code
} else {
    return res.status(401).json({
        message: 'Niet bevoegd'
    });
}
```

Where req.session.user is undefined when doing the call from the front-end, but filled in through postman.
So I imagine that the problem lies within my Post method in angular.

Routing code:

```
var auth = jwt({
    secret: 'SECRET',
    userProperty: 'payload'
});

var producties = require('./producties.js'); 
router.post('/newproductie', auth, producties.newProductie);
```

EDIT: Maybe this can help, I used to have this working (I laid down the project for a while), but somehow it stopped working, I can't figure out why

EDIT 2: This also might solve this. I did a console.log(req.sessionID) and this prints out a new sessionID EVERY TIME I do a call to the backend. I can't figure out why. With Postman this works just fine

Comment: Can u please share the routing code?

Comment: Added the routing code

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     $http.post('http://url:3000/newproductie', {
                title: $scope.title,
                year: $scope.year},
 { 'headers': {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth.getToken() }
    }).success(function(data) {
                console.log("DATA",data);
                $location.path('/success')
            });
        }
```

Comment: Then I'd be missing the headers.Authorization sub so it'd need to become:
    {headers: { 'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + auth.getToken()}}
 But this gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!
Apparently after some real digging, it wasn't in my code after all (as I suspected).
So After some thinking I remembered I turned on a privacy feature in Safari that websites can't follow you, this is why every time I did an api call to the backend a new session was made.
Stupid...